# Are download usage statistics available through the iPhone API?

Tags: iphone, sdk

i'm referring to the cellular usage stats in settings->general->usage
(documented or undocumented API is ok).

I'm also looking for APIs to the wifi statistics as well.

Answer (score 1):

None of this is available to app developers.

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring