# iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets

I've searched over this topic but found very few details which were helpful. With these details I've tried to cook some code as follows.

**Note: Please compare the details shared in this post with other posts before marking this as DUPLICATE, and not just by the subject.**

```
- (NSArray *)getDataCountersForType:(int)type {
    BOOL success;
    struct ifaddrs *addrs = nil;
    const struct ifaddrs *cursor = nil;
    const struct sockaddr_dl *dlAddr = nil;
    const struct if_data *networkStatisc = nil; 

    int dataSent = 0;
    int dataReceived = 0;

    success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
    if (success) {
        cursor = addrs;
        while (cursor != NULL) {
            if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK) {
                dlAddr = (const struct sockaddr_dl *) cursor->ifa_addr;
                networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;

                if (type == WiFi) {
                    dataSent += networkStatisc->ifi_opackets;
                    dataReceived += networkStatisc->ifi_ipackets;   
                }
                else if (type == WWAN) {
                    dataSent += networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                    dataReceived += networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes; 
                }
            }
            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }
        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }       
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dataSent], [NSNumber numberWithInt:dataReceived], nil];    
}
```

This code collects information of internet usage of an iPhone device (and not my application alone).

Now, if I use internet through WiFi or through 3G, I get the the data (bytes) only in `ifi_obytes` (sent) and `ifi_ibytes` (received) but I think I should get WiFi usage in `ifi_opackets` and `ifi_ipackets`.

Also wanted to add that if I'm connected to a WiFi network, but am not using internet, I still get value added to `ifi_obytes` and `ifi_ibytes`.

May be I'm wrong in the implementation or understanding. Need someone to help me out.

---

Edit: Instead of `AF_LINK` I tried `AF_INET` (`sockaddr_in` instead of `sockaddr_dl`). This crashes the application.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The thing is that `pdp_ip0` is one of interfaces, all `pdpXXX` are `WWAN` interfaces dedicated to different functions, voicemail, general networking interface.

I read in Apple forum that :
The OS does not keep network statistics on a process-by-process basis. As such, there's no exact solution to this problem. You can, however, get network statistics for each network interface.

In general `en0` is your `Wi-Fi` interface and `pdp_ip0` is your `WWAN` interface.

There is no good way to get  information wifi/cellular network data since, particular date-time!

Data statistic (`ifa_data->ifi_obytes` and `ifa_data->ifi_ibytes`) are stored from previous device reboot.

I don't know why, but `ifi_opackets` and `ifi_ipackets` are shown just for `lo0` (I think its main interface ).

Yes. Then  device is connected via `WiFi` and doesn't use internet `if_iobytes` values still come because this method provides network  bytes exchanges and not just internet.

```
#include <net/if.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>

static NSString *const DataCounterKeyWWANSent = @"WWANSent";
static NSString *const DataCounterKeyWWANReceived = @"WWANReceived";
static NSString *const DataCounterKeyWiFiSent = @"WiFiSent";
static NSString *const DataCounterKeyWiFiReceived = @"WiFiReceived";

NSDictionary *DataCounters()
{
    struct ifaddrs *addrs;
    const struct ifaddrs *cursor;

    u_int32_t WiFiSent = 0;
    u_int32_t WiFiReceived = 0;
    u_int32_t WWANSent = 0;
    u_int32_t WWANReceived = 0;

    if (getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0)
    {
        cursor = addrs;
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
            {
#ifdef DEBUG
                const struct if_data *ifa_data = (struct if_data *)cursor->ifa_data;
                if (ifa_data != NULL)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Interface name %s: sent %tu received %tu",cursor->ifa_name,ifa_data->ifi_obytes,ifa_data->ifi_ibytes);
                }
#endif

                // name of interfaces:
                // en0 is WiFi
                // pdp_ip0 is WWAN
                NSString *name = @(cursor->ifa_name);
                if ([name hasPrefix:@"en"])
                {
                    const struct if_data *ifa_data = (struct if_data *)cursor->ifa_data;
                    if (ifa_data != NULL)
                    {
                        WiFiSent += ifa_data->ifi_obytes;
                        WiFiReceived += ifa_data->ifi_ibytes;
                    }
                }

                if ([name hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip"])
                {
                    const struct if_data *ifa_data = (struct if_data *)cursor->ifa_data;
                    if (ifa_data != NULL)
                    {
                        WWANSent += ifa_data->ifi_obytes;
                        WWANReceived += ifa_data->ifi_ibytes;
                    }
                }
            }

            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }

        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }

    return @{DataCounterKeyWiFiSent : @(WiFiSent),
             DataCounterKeyWiFiReceived : @(WiFiReceived),
             DataCounterKeyWWANSent : @(WWANSent),
             DataCounterKeyWWANReceived : @(WWANReceived)};
}
```

**Improved copy/paste support !**

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code worked wonders. Also thanks for explaining the stuff.

Comment: You need to import this libraries:
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the data usage counters get reset on device reboot?

Comment: Yes. Usage counters are equal to zero after device reboot !

Comment: Is it possible with this code to track data traffic per iOS application ?

Comment: Yes. But not exact, data statistic are stored from previos device reboot.

Comment: @Sahil Could i know if you have used this code in some AppStore apps?

Comment: @Mat: The solution I've designed if for enterprise clients and is not deployed on the AppStore.

Comment: I would like to know why the values doesn't match the ones provided by the system (I've restored statistics and rebooted device)

Comment: Yes. This code still works! :)
I copied it from this post and build it again with no problems.

Comment: Can we find out data usage by each application?
@fvisticot did you get any solution please help me.

Comment: @Sahil Are you aware of any objection Apple if the app needed to go through the approval process?

Comment: @SKG: The solution I've designed is for enterprise clients and is not deployed on the AppStore. However I dont see anything in the code that violates Apple's policy. All APIs used are public. I suggest you upload the app to the AppStore and share the results.

Comment: Is this public API? In other words would the app store accept an app that uses this?

Comment: What about finding the same on cellular network. without wifi !

Comment: I'm using this code in my app and it seems like for some users it's returning negative values. How can that be?

Comment: Has anybody figured out how to get the data per app? Share the code please :)

Comment: @user982705  how did you handle the reset-on-reboot condition for monitoring data usage?

Comment: @Eddy, try replacing the type "int" with "unsigned int". You seem to experience an overflow problem which results in negative values.

Comment: I have rewritten code a little bit now it can be copied and pasted without additional pains

Comment: is the above code snippet for a application or device ?

Comment: @user982705 Can you tell me the minimum deployment target to implement this code ? will it support iOS 6 ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this , and with this i can get the network stat on each interface , But is it possible for me to take network usage based on app ???

Comment: @user982705 , Is it possible for us to access it from ifa_data64 structure ? since it returns the value as u_int64_t as per the if_var.h file . Can you please refer and tell ?

Comment: Can I Know the time duration the wifi was used and which wifi it was connected to?

Comment: @user982705 how can I track data usage application wise?

Comment: The comments in the code says "en0 is WiFi" but the code sums bytes from all if_data structs starting with "en". On my device I have en0, en1, en2... Should it just be en0?

Comment: Is it possible to track single application data transmission usage?

Comment: The bytes for WWAN represents the amount of data since last reboot? How can I get the data usage for custom period of time?

Comment: @Slavcho did you get the data usage for custom period of time?

Comment: @jarvis12 No. I think it is not possible. Maybe I'm wrong but so far i didn't find solution.

Comment: @Slavcho see [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bandwidth/id490461369?mt=12) guy is doing.

Comment: For all the noobs out there like me, you have to put the `#include` statements in the .h file and the rest in the the .m file. In React Native that's AppDelegate.h for the include statements and AppDelegate.m for the rest!

Answer (score 17):

It's important to understand that these counters are provided **since the device's last boot.**

So, to make effective use of them, you should accompany every sample with the device's uptime (you can use `mach_absolute_time()` - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450737/what-is-mach-absolute-time-based-on-on-iphone) for more information)

Once you have counters samples + uptime you can have better heuristics as to data use...

Comment: mach_absolute_time is not uptime. It is roughly the amount of time the CPU has been active. mach_absolute_time mostly stops counting when the device sleeps.

Answer (score 15):

To add to the accepted answer, its important to realize that the amount of data displayed by the interface overflows and restarts at `0` after every `4 GB`, especially if you are using this code to calculate the difference between two readings. This is because `ifi_obytes` and `ifi_ibytes` are `uint_32` and their max value is `4294967295`.

Also, I recommend using `unsigned int`s for the variables containing the data sent and received. Regular `int`s have half the max value of an unsigned integer, so when adding `ifi_obytes`, it may cause an overflow.

```
unsigned int sent = 0;
sent += networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift version of the accepted answer. I also break the code into smaller units.

```
struct DataUsageInfo {
    var wifiReceived: UInt32 = 0
    var wifiSent: UInt32 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataReceived: UInt32 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataSent: UInt32 = 0

    mutating func updateInfoByAdding(info: DataUsageInfo) {
        wifiSent += info.wifiSent
        wifiReceived += info.wifiReceived
        wirelessWanDataSent += info.wirelessWanDataSent
        wirelessWanDataReceived += info.wirelessWanDataReceived
    }
}

class DataUsage {

    private static let wwanInterfacePrefix = "pdp_ip"
    private static let wifiInterfacePrefix = "en"

    class func getDataUsage() -> DataUsageInfo {
        var interfaceAddresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        guard getifaddrs(&interfaceAddresses) == 0 else { return dataUsageInfo }

        var pointer = interfaceAddresses
        while pointer != nil {
            guard let info = getDataUsageInfo(from: pointer) else {
                pointer = pointer.memory.ifa_next
                continue
            }
            dataUsageInfo.updateInfoByAdding(info)
            pointer = pointer.memory.ifa_next
        }

        freeifaddrs(interfaceAddresses)

        return dataUsageInfo
    }

    private class func getDataUsageInfo(from infoPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) -> DataUsageInfo? {
        let pointer = infoPointer

        let name: String! = String.fromCString(infoPointer.memory.ifa_name)

        let addr = pointer.memory.ifa_addr.memory
        guard addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) else { return nil }

        return dataUsageInfo(from: pointer, name: name)
    }

    private class func dataUsageInfo(from pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>, name: String) -> DataUsageInfo {
        var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data> = nil
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        if name.hasPrefix(wifiInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.memory.ifa_data, UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            dataUsageInfo.wifiSent += networkData.memory.ifi_obytes
            dataUsageInfo.wifiReceived += networkData.memory.ifi_ibytes
        } else if name.hasPrefix(wwanInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.memory.ifa_data, UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataSent += networkData.memory.ifi_obytes
            dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataReceived += networkData.memory.ifi_ibytes
        }

        return dataUsageInfo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed above source code to Swift3 version

```
struct DataUsageInfo {
    var wifiReceived: UInt32 = 0
    var wifiSent: UInt32 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataReceived: UInt32 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataSent: UInt32 = 0

    mutating func updateInfoByAdding(_ info: DataUsageInfo) {
        wifiSent += info.wifiSent
        wifiReceived += info.wifiReceived
        wirelessWanDataSent += info.wirelessWanDataSent
        wirelessWanDataReceived += info.wirelessWanDataReceived
    }
}


class DataUsage {

    private static let wwanInterfacePrefix = "pdp_ip"
    private static let wifiInterfacePrefix = "en"

    class func getDataUsage() -> DataUsageInfo {
        var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return dataUsageInfo }
        while let addr = ifaddr {
            guard let info = getDataUsageInfo(from: addr) else {
                ifaddr = addr.pointee.ifa_next
                continue
            }
            dataUsageInfo.updateInfoByAdding(info)
            ifaddr = addr.pointee.ifa_next
        }

        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

        return dataUsageInfo
    }

    private class func getDataUsageInfo(from infoPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) -> DataUsageInfo? {
        let pointer = infoPointer
        let name: String! = String(cString: pointer.pointee.ifa_name)
        let addr = pointer.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee
        guard addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) else { return nil }

        return dataUsageInfo(from: pointer, name: name)
    }

    private class func dataUsageInfo(from pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>, name: String) -> DataUsageInfo {
        var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>?
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        if name.hasPrefix(wifiInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            if let data = networkData {
                dataUsageInfo.wifiSent += data.pointee.ifi_obytes
                dataUsageInfo.wifiReceived += data.pointee.ifi_ibytes
            }

        } else if name.hasPrefix(wwanInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            if let data = networkData {
                dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataSent += data.pointee.ifi_obytes
                dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataReceived += data.pointee.ifi_ibytes
            }
        }

        return dataUsageInfo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A new version about based on previous versions, but adapted for Swift4 and Xcode 9

```
struct DataUsageInfo {
    var wifiReceived: UInt32 = 0
    var wifiSent: UInt32 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataReceived: UInt32 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataSent: UInt32 = 0

    mutating func updateInfoByAdding(info: DataUsageInfo) {
        wifiSent += info.wifiSent
        wifiReceived += info.wifiReceived
        wirelessWanDataSent += info.wirelessWanDataSent
        wirelessWanDataReceived += info.wirelessWanDataReceived
    }
}

class DataUsage {

    private static let wwanInterfacePrefix = "pdp_ip"
    private static let wifiInterfacePrefix = "en"

    class func getDataUsage() -> DataUsageInfo {
        var interfaceAddresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil

        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        guard getifaddrs(&interfaceAddresses) == 0 else { return dataUsageInfo }

        var pointer = interfaceAddresses
        while pointer != nil {
            guard let info = getDataUsageInfo(from: pointer!) else {
                pointer = pointer!.pointee.ifa_next
                continue
            }
            dataUsageInfo.updateInfoByAdding(info: info)
            pointer = pointer!.pointee.ifa_next
        }

        freeifaddrs(interfaceAddresses)

        return dataUsageInfo
    }

    private class func getDataUsageInfo(from infoPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) -> DataUsageInfo? {
        let pointer = infoPointer

        let name: String! = String(cString: infoPointer.pointee.ifa_name)
        let addr = pointer.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee
        guard addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) else { return nil }

        return dataUsageInfo(from: pointer, name: name)
    }

    private class func dataUsageInfo(from pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>, name: String) -> DataUsageInfo {
        var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>? = nil
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        if name.hasPrefix(wifiInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            dataUsageInfo.wifiSent += networkData?.pointee.ifi_obytes ?? 0
            dataUsageInfo.wifiReceived += networkData?.pointee.ifi_ibytes ?? 0
        } else if name.hasPrefix(wwanInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataSent += networkData?.pointee.ifi_obytes ?? 0
            dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataReceived += networkData?.pointee.ifi_ibytes ?? 0
        }

        return dataUsageInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: does it show for each app or the actual app where it's used?

Comment: It's the global usage... It's not separated by app.

Comment: And the value is from the last reboot. No way of getting for the past/current month?

Comment: @Slavcho. Until this post date it was not possible. I still didn't do a new research about it after iOS12. I recommend you to accumulate ir in some place to recovery it after.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for same answer again.

but I found that UInt32 is not enough, so it crashes when it became too big.

I just changed UInt32 to UInt64 and it works fine.

```
struct DataUsageInfo {
    var wifiReceived: UInt64 = 0
    var wifiSent: UInt64 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataReceived: UInt64 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataSent: UInt64 = 0

    mutating func updateInfoByAdding(info: DataUsageInfo) {
        wifiSent += info.wifiSent
        wifiReceived += info.wifiReceived
        wirelessWanDataSent += info.wirelessWanDataSent
        wirelessWanDataReceived += info.wirelessWanDataReceived
    }
}

class DataUsage {

    private static let wwanInterfacePrefix = "pdp_ip"
    private static let wifiInterfacePrefix = "en"

    class func getDataUsage() -> DataUsageInfo {
        var interfaceAddresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil

        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        guard getifaddrs(&interfaceAddresses) == 0 else { return dataUsageInfo }

        var pointer = interfaceAddresses
        while pointer != nil {
            guard let info = getDataUsageInfo(from: pointer!) else {
                pointer = pointer!.pointee.ifa_next
                continue
            }
            dataUsageInfo.updateInfoByAdding(info: info)
            pointer = pointer!.pointee.ifa_next
        }

        freeifaddrs(interfaceAddresses)

        return dataUsageInfo
    }

    private class func getDataUsageInfo(from infoPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) -> DataUsageInfo? {
        let pointer = infoPointer

        let name: String! = String(cString: infoPointer.pointee.ifa_name)
        let addr = pointer.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee
        guard addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) else { return nil }

        return dataUsageInfo(from: pointer, name: name)
    }

    private class func dataUsageInfo(from pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>, name: String) -> DataUsageInfo {
        var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>? = nil
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        if name.hasPrefix(wifiInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            dataUsageInfo.wifiSent += UInt64(networkData?.pointee.ifi_obytes ?? 0)
            dataUsageInfo.wifiReceived += UInt64(networkData?.pointee.ifi_ibytes ?? 0)
        } else if name.hasPrefix(wwanInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataSent += UInt64(networkData?.pointee.ifi_obytes ?? 0)
            dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataReceived += UInt64(networkData?.pointee.ifi_ibytes ?? 0)
        }

        return dataUsageInfo
    }
}
```