# Is there any API for developers to monitor the 3G/WIFI/GPRS signals?

Tags: iphone, wifi, 3g, packet-capture, gprs

I want to capture the iPhone's network traffic. Will Apple allow us to do this? Are there any APIs for the developer to monitor the signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "flow" you mean all the data being sent and received by those mechanisms, then no - you can't do this on a non-jailbroken iPhone. Apps are restricted from interfering with anything the system processes or other applications do.

Comment: I see some Apps can do this in itunes store?  That means, Apple allow developer to do this or the app using other method to monitor it?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/id425315731?mt=8   http://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/id432905116?mt=8 And,I find some info about this,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring  I don't know whether it work well?

Comment: Ah, these are getting the total number of packets going through each interface, from which you can estimate a data usage level. That other question is a good answer to that, if that's your problem.

Comment: The answer is very good. But ,it only getting the total number of packets going through each interface. Can I get every App's data? And,the data is reset when user reboot his iphone.

Comment: No, you can't. As per my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture IP traffic, and your iPhone is running iOS 5 or later, and you can hook your iPhone up to a machine running OS X, you can use the [remote virtual interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECRVI) mechanism, which funnels a copy of the network traffic to the Mac to be captured with your favorite network tool (tcpdump, Wireshark, etc.).

If you want to capture traffic at a lower level, you could capture Wi-Fi traffic with a Wi-Fi adapter in monitor mode (but be prepared to have to decrypt the traffic; see [the Wireshark "how to decrypt 802.11" page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) for information on that), but you will have extreme difficulty capturing raw mobile-phone-network traffic (you probably won't be able to).