# Is it possible to build this iPhone app? (phone usage/consumption monitoring)

Tags: android, iphone, ios, telephony

I built an Android app that monitors the user's consumption: sent/received SMS, incoming/outgoing calls, bytes of data sent/received via mobile internet and via WiFi/LAN, and the network roaming state during any of those transactions. My client uses the info to match the user with the best mobile plan according to his/her usage data. I'm now being asked to create an iOS version of the app, but since I'm new to iPhone development, I'm not even sure if it's possible. So, my questions are...

1. Is it possible to detect when the user sends or receives an SMS? I need to be able to log the time when they were sent or received, the originating and target mobile numbers, the network roaming state, and number of characters inside the SMS. It looks like this isn't possible from my current research (the iOS SDK only allows you to send SMSes), but the answers I've read are from about 2 years ago.
2. Is it possible to detect the incoming/outgoing calls? I need to be able to log the time when the call started, when the call was answered, and when it ended. From what I've read, there's the `CTCallCenter` class, but it doesn't look like I can use it when my app is in the background. I need something more like Android's `BroadcastReceiver` that fires a system-wide event that I can catch when a call arrives or is being made.
3. Is it possible to get the number of bytes sent/received via the mobile interface (3G, 4G), and via the network interface (WiFi)? The only documentation I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring), but it doesn't make any sense to me.
4. Is it possible to get the network roaming state during any of those transactions? What I've found is that it's possible, but only if I jailbreak the phone. Problem is, I need to be able to do all of the above without jailbreaking the iPhone.

Help? Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd be much better separating this out into separate questions. It'll be much easier to answer that way, and will be a better fit for StackOverflow's Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

sorry AFAIK its not possible:

- 1 = no
- 2 = no
- 3 = yes
- 4 = no

Comment: About #2: How about the call logs? Can I at least access it? I'm thinking of firing a thread during a scheduled period of time, read the call logs, and get what I can get from there (incoming, outgoing, missed calls).

Comment: no those belong to the phone app and cant be read on iphones -- EXCEPT if the phone is jailbroken? .... is this for jailbroken phones?

Comment: No, it's not for jailbroken phones.

Comment: pitty, then the no stays :)

Comment: The calls seem traceable though if you make it from inside the app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/call-timer/id448968332?mt=8