# Capture Network data usage by each Application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

I want to make an iPhone application in which Network data usage by each application is detected and shown.
Just like Onavo Count
*I don't care if Apple don't support it. I am not going to sale it*

Comment: [Good point to start](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8014012/1407017)

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for something which tells me how much data used by each application

Comment: By "data usage," do you mean disk space, memory, network bandwidth, cpu usage?

Comment: Onavo Count use a VPN to do this. Each app's data will be send to its server.