# ObjectiveC-Code to track the data usage from my application in iphone

Tags: iphone

I would like to know how much data is transferred specifically from my application?I have tried code given in link
 [iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring)
this gives the whole data transmitted from all apps.But,my requirement is to fetch data only from my app.

Comment: Publish what you've tried so far (code, not links) so others can point out the problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use easily Google Analytics.
It will give you a lot of information and statistics about your application.

Try it in your application : [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/)