# AVPlayer Data Usage

Tags: ios, avplayer, network-traffic

I'm streaming audio from url by AVPlayer class. How can i get data usage counters (bytes) from AVPlayer or by another way.
I've tried this [iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring?lq=1)

but can't get data usage only for my application.

Update:
also i tried:

```
self.aPlayer.currentItem.accessLog
AVPlayerItemAccessLog *accesslog = self.aPlayer.currentItem.accessLog;  
NSArray *events = [accesslog events];    
AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent *event = [events objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSLog(@"Number of bytes received %@", [event numberOfBytesTransferred]);
```

but it doesn't work for me. Events array always empty.

Comment: We observe the same thing here. The accessLog is always present, but for audio live streams there are no events. VOD, AOD and Video Lives all have events...

Comment: @onekiloparsec, did you found a solution for the empty event array for audio live streams? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: nope. no solution found. we worked out something else. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An AVAsset can be loaded by *both* a local or remote URL via the NSURLConnection class and the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol, which provides methods that the NSURLConnection class calls with progress information during an upload—including bytes transferred.