# Data usage split on iOS7

Tags: ios7

Does anyone know if data usage split per application and per network (roaming, cell, wifi) can be extracted from iOS7?
For example i would like my app to display on day D, twitter = 10Mo roaming, Angrybird=X Mo on wifi.
Alternatively any reference on a company having such an app or able to code it would be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access traffic counters per network interface (e.g. Wifi, 3G) but not per application.  Good explanation in here [iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring)