# how to check data usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

Hi take days looking information about this and I have found absolutely nothing, is there app like Onavo using a proxy, but some do not and I need to know how much data I'm consuming at one point to see if it is producing for such a shock, I need a lot of help if they have some information please help. for example:

[image: for example]

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how much data your APP is consuming? Or are you trying to tell the overall data usage of the device?

Comment: I would like to know the general use of the device

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea about this question.  I'm sure there are ignorant people like me who don't know what Onavo is.  I do know what iPhone and iPad are.

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring

Comment: probe and the sample does not serve me, this example tells you the data traffic sent and received, but a few test hize tranferia when I was browsing safari and transferred few when I download an app and it was practically the same, so keep looking other response

Comment: Onavo creates a VPN connection which compresses inbound traffic (HTTP) via there CDN. Your best solution would be to use a VPN network which show statistics

Comment: there is no other way to achieve this, there is no api able to give a solution for this?