# How to calculate cellular data usage on IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm doing a Radio app right now. My customer is asking to implement the cellular data usage. Can someone help me how to calculate the data usage? Or is there any API to get the data usage? Could somebody suggest a simple way to calculate cellular data usage, if there is no APIs available?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring

Answer (score -2):

See [iOS 7 How-to: Monitor & track your cellular data usage](http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/25/ios-7-how-to-monitor-track-your-cellular-data-usage/) and [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-data-manager-track-your/id477865384?mt=8).

Comment: I know there is a iphone feature to see the data usages for each app!! But my radio app should calculate and show up the data usage separately.