# Get downloading progress in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sockets

As we konw for the iPhone Device we can use "ifaddrs" to monitoring the user's data. reference to this link:"[iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring)", but how to monitoring the download data of current process in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLSessionDownloadTask and implement it's delegate

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
     downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
     didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
  NSLog(@"%f / %f", (double)totalBytesWritten,
    (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}
```

Complete tutorial can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial