# Is getifaddrs public API on IOS?

Tags: ios, app-store

I need to find out my user's data usage and I'm seeing there's a way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring)

But is this API public? In other words would the App Store accept, or reject it?

Comment: Since Apple provides the documentation for the `getifaddrs` function, it is public. Therefore that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used getifaddrs for years without problems.

It is documented with man pages, and is from the BSD library, so I think you are on rock solid ground here.

The problem you're going to meet is that the iOS implementation ( for most devices) uses 32bit pointers, so you have to code around overflow.  This is non-trivial and there are a few gotchas ( I'm currently trying to find out why the counts can go backwards by a few tens of bytes!).