# Track cellular data usage using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Is there any way to track cellular data used by device in swift? Is there any api? I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dataman-next-track-data-usage/id592962356?mt=8)

Comment: Check out __[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring/8014012#8014012)__. It is for Objective - C, but I think you could change it with little effort to make it work in Swift.

Comment: But how can you know how much data have you used in a custom period of time, like the current month or from 25th till 25th next month?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Updated to Swift 4 you can use this easy extension. To track the device cell and wifi Usage.

```
extension SystemDataUsage {

    public static var wifiCompelete: UInt64 {
        return SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wifiSent + SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wifiReceived
    }

    public static var wwanCompelete: UInt64 {
        return SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wirelessWanDataSent + SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wirelessWanDataReceived
    }

}

class SystemDataUsage {

    private static let wwanInterfacePrefix = "pdp_ip"
    private static let wifiInterfacePrefix = "en"

    class func getDataUsage() -> DataUsageInfo {
        var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return dataUsageInfo }
        while let addr = ifaddr {
            guard let info = getDataUsageInfo(from: addr) else {
                ifaddr = addr.pointee.ifa_next
                continue
            }
            dataUsageInfo.updateInfoByAdding(info)
            ifaddr = addr.pointee.ifa_next
        }

        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

        return dataUsageInfo
    }

    private class func getDataUsageInfo(from infoPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) -> DataUsageInfo? {
        let pointer = infoPointer
        let name: String! = String(cString: pointer.pointee.ifa_name)
        let addr = pointer.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee
        guard addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) else { return nil }

        return dataUsageInfo(from: pointer, name: name)
    }

    private class func dataUsageInfo(from pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>, name: String) -> DataUsageInfo {
        var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>?
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        if name.hasPrefix(wifiInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            if let data = networkData {
                dataUsageInfo.wifiSent += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_obytes)
                dataUsageInfo.wifiReceived += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_ibytes)
            }

        } else if name.hasPrefix(wwanInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            if let data = networkData {
                dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataSent += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_obytes)
                dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataReceived += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_ibytes)
            }
        }
        return dataUsageInfo
    }
}

struct DataUsageInfo {
    var wifiReceived: UInt64 = 0
    var wifiSent: UInt64 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataReceived: UInt64 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataSent: UInt64 = 0

    mutating func updateInfoByAdding(_ info: DataUsageInfo) {
        wifiSent += info.wifiSent
        wifiReceived += info.wifiReceived
        wirelessWanDataSent += info.wirelessWanDataSent
        wirelessWanDataReceived += info.wirelessWanDataReceived
    }
}
```

You can use it like: `SystemDataUsage.wifiCompelete`

Comment: this usage is for overall device or single app

Comment: Thanks for the code! If you can, would you please add comments or explain your code? Thank you!

Comment: this will reply total usage of device at time of execution or only provide our app usage...?????

Comment: It's for the device. As you see we accessing the device wifi and wwan interface @UsmanNisar

Comment: Is there any way to get the data usage for certain application?

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer returns data in Bytes.
SystemDataUsage.wifiCompelete

This information could be helpful for someone.