# Track VPN Data Usage Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

I am using Personel VPN on iOS. -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/personal_vpn

I want to track upload and download usage when user connected the VPN.
But i couldn't find any methods on NEVPNManager.

Is there any way to track data usage when connected the VPN?

Or should i track data usage like these methods-> [Track cellular data usage using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888272/track-cellular-data-usage-using-swift)

But these methods tracks all usage. I should clamp to get correct data usage.
Because i want to track data usage when connected the VPN.