# Swift - How can I determine the amount of data (cellular / WiFi) my app has been consuming?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that it is possible to track cellular and WiFi data usage for an entire iOS device in Swift (source: [Track cellular data usage using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888272/track-cellular-data-usage-using-swift)).

Can I track the amount of data used by my app? I'm interested in all data (HttpClient, AVAudioPlayer, etc.) The reason for this is better diagnostics.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Yes, but apparently there is no solution for this as of today :(