# Tracking iPhone Data Usage

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone please help me how I can get the Data Usage from WWAN and WLAN with Swift?

I found on Stack Overflow how to do that in Objective-C but an explanation would be nice!

[Here is how to do that in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring).

Comment: Did you try rewriting the method yourself? It's a fun exercise.

Comment: so it's to complex ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Swift 4

#### Sample Usage

```
let usage = getDataUsage()

// prints '3527660544 bytes of wifi'
print("\(usage.wifi.sent) bytes of wifi")

// prints '3.29 GB of wifi'
let usageString = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(usage.wifi.sent), countStyle: .binary)
print("\(usageString) of wifi")
```

#### Code

```
import Foundation

typealias DataUsage = (wifi: (sent: UInt32, received: UInt32), wwan: (sent: UInt32, received: UInt32))

func getDataUsage() -> DataUsage {
    var interfaceAddresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?

    let status = getifaddrs(&interfaceAddresses)
    defer { freeifaddrs(interfaceAddresses) }

    var returnData = DataUsage((0, 0), (0, 0))

    guard status == 0, let addresses = interfaceAddresses else { return returnData }

    for pointer in AddressSequence(interfaceAddresses: addresses) {
        guard pointer.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family == AF_LINK else { continue }
        let networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
        let (bytesIn, bytesOut) = (networkData.pointee.ifi_ibytes, networkData.pointee.ifi_obytes)

        let name = String(cString: pointer.pointee.ifa_name)
        if name.hasPrefix("en") {
            returnData.wifi.sent += bytesOut
            returnData.wifi.received += bytesIn
        } else if name.hasPrefix("pdp_ip") {
            returnData.wwan.sent += bytesOut
            returnData.wwan.received += bytesIn
        }
    }

    return returnData
}

class AddressSequence: Sequence {
    init(interfaceAddresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) {
        self.interfaceAddresses = interfaceAddresses
    }

    let interfaceAddresses: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>

    typealias Element = UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>

    func makeIterator() -> AddressIterator {
        return AddressIterator(currentPointer: interfaceAddresses)
    }
}

class AddressIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    init(currentPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) {
        self.currentPointer = currentPointer
    }

    var currentPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?

    public func next() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? {
        currentPointer = currentPointer?.pointee.ifa_next ?? nil
        return currentPointer
    }
}
```

---

### Old Version

Here's one possible implementation.

First, include `ifaddrs` in your Objective-C bridging header:

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
```

Then, try out this function:

```
func getDataUsage() -> (wifi : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32), wwan : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32)) {
    var interfaceAddresses : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
    var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data> = nil

    var returnTuple : (wifi : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32), wwan : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32)) = ((0, 0), (0, 0))

    if getifaddrs(&interfaceAddresses) == 0 {
        for var pointer = interfaceAddresses; pointer != nil; pointer = pointer.memory.ifa_next {

            let name : String! = String.fromCString(pointer.memory.ifa_name)
            println(name);
            let flags = Int32(pointer.memory.ifa_flags)
            var addr = pointer.memory.ifa_addr.memory

            if addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) {
                if name.hasPrefix("en") {
                    networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.memory.ifa_data, UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
                    returnTuple.wifi.sent += networkData.memory.ifi_obytes
                    returnTuple.wifi.received += networkData.memory.ifi_ibytes
                } else if name.hasPrefix("pdp_ip") {
                    networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.memory.ifa_data, UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
                    returnTuple.wwan.sent += networkData.memory.ifi_obytes
                    returnTuple.wwan.received += networkData.memory.ifi_ibytes
                }
            }
        }

        freeifaddrs(interfaceAddresses)
    }

    return returnTuple
}
```

It returns nested Swift tuples representing the four pieces of data you requested. This makes it easy to access. For example:

```
let usage = getDataUsage()
let wifiDataSentString = "WiFi Data Sent: \(usage.wifi.sent)"
```

Comment: Thanks I'm check that :) So I'm really new in IOS Dev so it will help me a lot !

Comment: the function only return's 0 data usage ?:(

Comment: @BilalReffas It's working for me. How are you running it?

Comment: when i pressed a button than i run the function ? like you init that

Comment: the bridging header and everything it's correct..:( the wifi and wwan usage returns 0 :(

Comment: @BilalReffas Try my updated version - see if it works for you.

Comment: thanks it works right now :) the number i get it's in byte or kilobyte or mb ?

Comment: Okay Thanks:) it's possible to reset the data usage counter ?

Comment: @BilalReffas Not to my knowledge. I think it resets when the device restarts.

Comment: So there is no way to get for a specific time, like previous month or so? The returned value is from the last device reboot till now?

Answer (score 0):

Updated @Aaron Brager answer for Swift 4 and Xcode 9.

```
func getDataUsage() -> (wifi : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32), wwan : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32)) {
    var interfaceAddresses : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil
    var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>? = nil
    var pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil

    var returnTuple : (wifi : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32), wwan : (sent : UInt32, received : UInt32)) = ((0, 0), (0, 0))

    if getifaddrs(&interfaceAddresses) == 0 {
        pointer = interfaceAddresses
        while pointer != nil {
            let name : String = String.init(validatingUTF8: pointer!.pointee.ifa_name)!
            let flags = UInt32((pointer?.pointee.ifa_flags)!)//Int32(pointer?.pointee.ifa_flags)
            let addr = pointer?.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee

            if addr?.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) {
                    if name.hasPrefix("en") {
                        networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer?.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
                        returnTuple.wifi.sent += (networkData?.pointee.ifi_obytes)!
                        returnTuple.wifi.received += (networkData?.pointee.ifi_ibytes)!
                    } else if name.hasPrefix("pdp_ip") {
                        networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer?.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
                        returnTuple.wwan.sent += (networkData?.pointee.ifi_obytes)!
                        returnTuple.wwan.received += (networkData?.pointee.ifi_ibytes)!
                    }
                }

            pointer = pointer?.pointee.ifa_next
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(interfaceAddresses)

    return returnTuple
}
```