# How to get Notification/Event when Any App is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios9

I am developing an `app` which is tracking the `Internet Data` consumes by any app.

I searched a lot but doesn't find anything fruitful. I am in a doubt that this might be unfeasible in `iOS` to acheive.

What I want is that if my application is running background and user launches any `app` then I want to track which app is launched.

Is it possible to do in `iOS`?

Comment: For data tracking you can use this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring. But I doubt if any app can track other app's launch.

Answer (score 0):

In general this would violate the sandbox principle, hence it's not possible.

Comment: But I saw some apps in appstore which are working on same principle

Comment: I agree with @DrMickeyLauer that this is not possible on iOS. Can you mention which apps you saw that are working this way?