# Get the network traffic statics on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, networking, traffic

I want to display the network traffic statistics in my iOS application. For that, I must detect the sent and received bytes and also the latency. I spent multiple hours on searching but I didn't find what I'm expecting.

What is the best way to do that? In Android there is the `TrafficStats` class that allows to get the sent and received bytes. What about iOS?

Comment: have you checked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Yes but I didn't really understand the logic. Can you explain me please?

Comment: Basically, the answer suggests monitoring the statistics on the network card relating to mobile data (WWAN). There's a Swift API library that lets you access the part that reports on data downloaded *since the device was last booted/restarted*. Also, because of the limitations of how large a number the variable type return can hold, the counter resets after slightly more than 4 GB. You can use that to calculate all the latency you need.