# How to monitor the network bandwidth usage of a specific iOS application?

Tags: ios, networking, bandwidth

I am working on video application for iPhone , user can click and view videos also Annotate videos and share it to social networks.Network bandwidth plays vital role in our application.

How to monitor the network usages of my application users?

In case of data consumption goes into higher volume , needs to optimize the network usage of my application.

Any Libraries or 3rd party tools to monitor the network usage?

Any Analytical report tools helps to understand the network usage of my application?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: I think a similar question has been answered on SO. Please refer to the link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring". Please let me know if this is what you wanted