# Access ifa_data64 struct from if_var.h file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with objective c and have successfully developed apps for iOS . Currently , I am working with using this file called `if_var.h` file . There are two structures inside this file named `if_data` and `if_data64` which have same members and definition except for their return  types. When I access `if_data` structure , everything works fine and I wanted to know how can I access the `ia_data64` structure as it returns the data in u_int64_t format ! can anyone help ?

Comment: can you post some code for both structure so can get idea how you are calling this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8014012/6033431 refer this post . I am analysing the data used . And it works fine . However if you can see this - https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/net/if_var.h , you ll see that there are two structures. I want to access the second one

Comment: @CodeChanger , Should I provide you with anymore details ?

Comment: No its enough for me but what my next question what you need to achieve by this structure ? where actually you are using this one ?

Comment: The first one returns u_int32_t. And the counter resets after 4 gb . So I want to access the second structure so that it returns u_int64_t and the counter doesn't overflow. Understanding ?