# Can we find historical data usage(Wifi / Mobile Data) of the installed application through libimobiledevice or iOS APIs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, libimobiledevice

I have used this,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014012/8390144

This code gives only WiFi & WWAN Data usage of device from last reboot.This gives total data usage (not app specific).Please find image.

Note: This is not duplicate.I want App specific Data usage (WiFi & Cellular) from iOS APIs or **libimobile packages.**

- I will use this for Enterprise Application,So It will be helpful if there are Third party/Private libraries/Framework.
- I want historic data, so creating VPN and routing network traffic is not useful.
- Not using for jailbroke Device.
- Is there any framework like Diagnostics.framework which gives all Historic data about battery?

[image: This much information we get]