# List all Apps and Track Internet Usage

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**Request: Do not mark this question as duplicate as have researched around and all questions are around 4 years old**

I came across an application which got me curious as to how it works -> [My Data Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/app/my-data-manager-track-data-usage-and-save-money/id477865384)

To track internet usage is ok and [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring/) using `ifaddrs`, however the data obtained here is very raw i.e it only tells the data send and received via type of network.

What is eye candy about the app mentioned above that it lists the data used per app.
Primarily each app being sandboxed, is inaccessible to other applications (other than some public API methods of which overuse causes to [rejection of application](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp))

My questions:

1. How to get list of all applications installed on iOS device?
2. How to track internet usage per application?

I look forward to do both on non-jailbroken device.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, Apple is really concerned about privacy and security and won't allow something like that. You can still have a look at the project appbleed https://github.com/PierreBlazquez/appbleed-ios, but this will never pass Apple submission

Comment: @DamienBannerot The question still remains: how did My Data Manager do it?

Comment: They might use "func canOpenURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool"

Comment: @DamienBannerot - I had that researched and have added a link to it. It causes application rejection by Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use VPN configurations to monitor your network usage. Attached here is the screen from their app. If you give permissions they will add a VPN configuration to your settings. Check [out](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/) on how to do that

[A screenshot from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Yb2.png)

Comment: That was a great conclusion. Thanks