# How to get all app list and data usage of that app in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

### Request:Please do not mark it as duplicate because i gone through many questions.

I want to create app in which i want all app from my iPhone / iPad with its data usage. I get an idea for that i need VPN but i don't know how to implement it in app. I gone through many question and answer but i don't get satisfied answer. So how could i achieve this problems solution?

i gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846209/list-all-apps-and-track-internet-usage) question but i am not fully satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You can't get list of all apps installed on your iPhone/iPad, if device is not jailbreaked.

In question your mentioned VPN was used to get info about apps that used network connection.

However event if you will implement it, you will not be able to see apps that not use network

Comment: Thanks @Taras u clear my half of the doubt now as u mention i get only the list of app that uses network i also want the same so how can i implement this in my code. sorry i am not able to give u reputation as i am having the reputation less than 15. But you really clear my doubt. Now please guid me how to get list of app that are using network.