# Swift - Get Mobile Data Current Usage figure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, settings, mobile-data

Is it possible to retrieve the value under ‘Current Period’ in the screenshot below?

[image]

And is there any way to programmatically reset this figure?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring

Comment: Sorry! no way to get access  Mobile Data Current Usage figure

Answer (score 2):

You can track cellular and wifi data usage using this extension

```
extension SystemDataUsage {

    public static var wifiCompelete: UInt64 {
        return SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wifiSent + SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wifiReceived
    }

    public static var wwanCompelete: UInt64 {
        return SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wirelessWanDataSent + SystemDataUsage.getDataUsage().wirelessWanDataReceived
    }

}

class SystemDataUsage {

    private static let wwanInterfacePrefix = "pdp_ip"
    private static let wifiInterfacePrefix = "en"

    class func getDataUsage() -> DataUsageInfo {
        var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return dataUsageInfo }
        while let addr = ifaddr {
            guard let info = getDataUsageInfo(from: addr) else {
                ifaddr = addr.pointee.ifa_next
                continue
            }
            dataUsageInfo.updateInfoByAdding(info)
            ifaddr = addr.pointee.ifa_next
        }

        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

        return dataUsageInfo
    }

    private class func getDataUsageInfo(from infoPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>) -> DataUsageInfo? {
        let pointer = infoPointer
        let name: String! = String(cString: pointer.pointee.ifa_name)
        let addr = pointer.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee
        guard addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) else { return nil }

        return dataUsageInfo(from: pointer, name: name)
    }

    private class func dataUsageInfo(from pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>, name: String) -> DataUsageInfo {
        var networkData: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>?
        var dataUsageInfo = DataUsageInfo()

        if name.hasPrefix(wifiInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            if let data = networkData {
                dataUsageInfo.wifiSent += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_obytes)
                dataUsageInfo.wifiReceived += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_ibytes)
            }

        } else if name.hasPrefix(wwanInterfacePrefix) {
            networkData = unsafeBitCast(pointer.pointee.ifa_data, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<if_data>.self)
            if let data = networkData {
                dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataSent += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_obytes)
                dataUsageInfo.wirelessWanDataReceived += UInt64(data.pointee.ifi_ibytes)
            }
        }
        return dataUsageInfo
    }
}

struct DataUsageInfo {
    var wifiReceived: UInt64 = 0
    var wifiSent: UInt64 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataReceived: UInt64 = 0
    var wirelessWanDataSent: UInt64 = 0

    mutating func updateInfoByAdding(_ info: DataUsageInfo) {
        wifiSent += info.wifiSent
        wifiReceived += info.wifiReceived
        wirelessWanDataSent += info.wirelessWanDataSent
        wirelessWanDataReceived += info.wirelessWanDataReceived
    }
}
```

usage :-

```
 SystemDataUsage.wifiCompelete
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track data usage while your app is in use. You cannot access download information when your app is not running. iOS prevents it for security reasons. You could save the value of 200MB to NSUserDefaults or another persistent store. Then you could reload that data on app launch.

Please have a look on [background running for IOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)

Comment: Would it be possible to track data usage by the apps running in the application and set the data limit for few of them? something like 100 MB/day for XYZ app.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is now way to access the information provided in the screenshot.
Only way I can think of fetching those cellular usage data is by creating a personal VPN and transferring all incoming and outgoing data through it.
That way you can track the data used by a specific application!

Check out this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager