# Flutter - Get Data usage continuously

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement to show the data that is currently being consumed from the mobile. For example, when user streams a video from YouTube or Instagram, the data consumption would be high and we would need to show the data that is being consumed (in MB/s) and when the user leaves the phone idle and if there are no background work then it would show 0kB/s. Is there a way to achieve this using Flutter or any other technology (if not feasible)?

Tried using internet speed and data usage but they only showed the actual download/upload speed

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring?answertab=votes#tab-top) for tracking data usage on iOS. On Android, you'd use the [`TrafficStats`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats) API. Then write a plugin so that your dart code receives the data using platform channels.